# Spacing between Header and Chapter Titles

Tags: spacing, header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I have the following template:

```
%Loading in the packages
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\restylefloat{table} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mkbibbold{\mknumalph{#1}}}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=1cm,
    xrightmargin=\parindent,
}

%Loading in the pagestyling
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LO, CE]{Section \thesection}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Test Paper}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LO, CE]{Section \thesection}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Test Paper}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

%Titlepage Information
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\huge}
\title{
    {\TEST PAPER}\\
    {\TEST UNIVERSITY}\\
}
\author{TEST TEST}
\date{12th June 2015}


%Actual Document Begins and is laid out%
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
%\input{chapters/Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist, style=custom_acronyms]

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

\chapter{Aims}
\input{chapters/Aims}

\chapter{History}
\input{chapters/History}

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{mistakes}

\chapter{improvments}

\chapter{results}

\chapter{analysis}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

however I am getting large spacing between the chapter headings and the actual header as seen below:
[image: space between header]

has anyone got any ideas for how to reduce this spacing? Also being a complete beginner I was hoping to display chapters in the format: number:title 1.Introduction but I have no idea how to do this, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `titlesec` package, that you've already loaded. I changed the code to make it compilable (e.g. the code gave errors such as: `missing \TEST definition` or `missing custom-acronym style definition`) and removed the packages not needed.

I decreased the space between the top margin and the title using `\vspace{...}`; you can change this value in order to get the desired output.

One note: latex gives a warning because the document is `oneside` but the settings of `fancyhdr` are for a `twoside` document (therefore, one setting is useless).

```
%Loading in the packages
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Random text
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Loading in the pagestyling
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LO, CE]{Section \thesection}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Test Paper}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LO, CE]{Section \thesection}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Test Paper}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

%Titlepage Information
\titleformat{\chapter}
            [hang] %shape (see titlesec package documentation)
            {\vspace{-2cm}\bfseries\Large}
            {\thechapter}
            {20pt} % distance between number and title
            {} 
            []

\title{
    {PAPER}\\
    {UNIVERSITY}\\
}
\author{TEST TEST}
\date{12th June 2015}


%Actual Document Begins and is laid out%
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
%\input{chapters/Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
%\input{chapters/Introduction}
\lipsum

\chapter{Aims}
%\input{chapters/Aims}
\lipsum

\chapter{History}
%\input{chapters/History}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```